# Write at least one function to simulate the rolling of dice

Tags: python, function, methods, dice

I have been tasked to write at least one function to simulate the rolling of dice and call that function in a loop for each player, find the total sum of dice roll though find myself heavily suffering from analysis paralysis.

sample output

```
How many players are rolling dice? 2
How many dice does each player roll? 3
How many sides does each die have? 6
Player 1 rolled:
4
2
4
That totals: 10
Player 2 rolled:
1
3
5
That totals: 9
```

My code so far

```
 import random

#User inputs 
r = int(input("How many times do you want to roll the dice? "))
s = int(input("how many sides do you want "))
p = int(input("How many players are rolling dice?"))

#Function Declaration  
def Rolldice(s,r):
  for i in range(0,r):
       die = random.randint(1, s)
       print(die)

#For loop that iterates through function declaration
for num in range(1,p+1):
  print(f"player {num} rolled")
  Rolldice(s,r)
  print(sum(Rolldice))
```

Though i am receiving error listed below

## TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: `print(sum(Rolldice))` `Rolldice` is your function, you cant iterate it

Comment: `print(sum(Rolldice))` can't work. `sum` expects an iterable that can literally be summed e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. You're passing it a function name. I've thought hard about how I can make an analogy to illustrate why this is incorrect but I'm drawing a blank.

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by the last line `print(sum(Rolldice))`. `Rolldice` is a function, you cannot sum over function. I suppose this should solve your problem -

```py
import random

#User inputs 
r = int(input("How many times do you want to roll the dice? "))
s = int(input("how many sides do you want "))
p = int(input("How many players are rolling dice?"))

#Function Declaration  
def Rolldice(s,r):
  dies = []
  for i in range(0,r):
       die = random.randint(1, s)
       print(die)
       dies.append(die)
  return dies

#For loop that iterates through function declaration
for num in range(1,p+1):
  print(f"player {num} rolled")
  dies = Rolldice(s,r)
  print("That totals:", sum(dies))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your last line:

`print(sum(Rolldice))`

You are actually passing a function to the `sum()` function. But if you check [the documentation for sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), it actually requires an iterable to be passed as an argument.

You should actually try to sum the results of your dice direcly in the `RollDice` function, and return the result.

```py
def Rolldice(s,r):
    total = 0
    for i in range(0,r):
        die = random.randint(1, s)
        print(die)
        sum += die
    return total
```

Now, you can finally print the total in your main function:

```py
for num in range(1,p+1):
    print(f"player {num} rolled")
    total = Rolldice(s,r)
    print(f"That totals: {total}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're cannot iterate over a function. However, you can iterate over it's results.
The first step to fix the code is to call the function and pass its results to `sum` instead of passing the function itself.
(You do call the function in the previous line but you don't use it's result in `sum`. This line could be removed.)

Replace `print(sum(Rolldice))` with `print(sum(Rolldice(s, r)))`.

Another problem is that you don't return value from the function. You just print it on the screen with `print`.
Normally returning a value is done via the keyword `return` but in this case you want to return multiple values. You could create an array of all the values and return it. It is nicely shown in the Vishwas Chepuri's answer.

However, in this case, you could use a generator. In simple words, it's a type of function that can be iterated over and return multiple values.
You can convert a normal function into a generator by returning value via `yield` keyword instead of `return`. In opposite to `return`, `yield` doesn't end the function.

Replace `print(die)` with `yield die`.

```py
import random

#User inputs 
r = int(input("How many times do you want to roll the dice? "))
s = int(input("how many sides do you want "))
p = int(input("How many players are rolling dice?"))

#Generator Declaration  
def Rolldice(s,r):
    for i in range(0,r):
        die = random.randint(1, s)
        yield die

#For loop that iterates through function declaration
for num in range(1,p+1):
    print(f"player {num} rolled")
    generator = Rolldice(s,r)
    print(sum(generator))
```

BTW, you can write `range(r)`, instead of `range(0,r)`. It means the same.